# Expand UITextView height (read more effect) in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, animation

I'm trying to expand UITextView with animation, when user tap read more button bellow it.

[image]

I've tried a lot of approaches and come up with almost working solution:

```
func readMore() {
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    cell.descTextViewHeightConstraint.constant = cell.descTextView.expectedHeight()
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

UItextView+Height

```
extension UITextView {
    func expectedHeight() -> CGFloat {
        let textView: UITextView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.size.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
        textView.font = self.font
        textView.text = self.text
        textView.sizeToFit()
        return textView.frame.height
    }
}
```

This solution works, but has one sideeffect - when the animation finishes, some of elements in the UITableViewCell are hidden (title label).

I've also tried to call tableView.reloadData() when the animation finishes, which works, but sometimes has sideeffects as well.

Comment: This question is asked almost everyday, that's why I created this example project https://github.com/bavarskis/ExpandingTableViewCell.git Look into it, it's very simple.

Comment: I've found a bug in my code, causing one of the side effect I've mentioned (button read more was not hidden when tapped). I was creating the read more button programatically in cellForRow function. The problem was, that when I scroll to that cell more than once, the button was created every time, and only the last one created was hidden on that.

Comment: @AuRis Where is Read More button /effect which the OP Asked ?

Comment: @AwaisFayyaz The example project shows how to update cell height while typing in its `UITextView`. Based on the example project you can easily implement Read More functionality. The project is not an answer to this particular question.

Comment: @filip.karas can you share your read more textview code ?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you "play" with the numberOfLines property?

For a project I did something similar like this (there was also a UIImage arrow that made a rotation...). Everything was inside a custom cell class:

```
func setExpanded(_ isExpanded: Bool) {
    if isExpanded {
        lblFullDescription.numberOfLines = 0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: Constants.NavigationBar.AnimationTime, animations: { [weak self] in
            self?.imgArrow.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi))
        })

    } else {
        lblFullDescription.numberOfLines = 2
        UIView.animate(withDuration: Constants.NavigationBar.AnimationTime, animations: { [weak self] in
            self?.imgArrow.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(0))
        })
    }
}
```

And add this in the ViewController that holds the UITableView:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 42
```

Comment: I've tried this approach. It's working, but the problem is that it animates "from bottom". When I set number of lines to 2, I can see first 2 lines of the content, which is good. But when I set number of lines to 0, I can see only last 2 lines of the content in the label (not first 2 lines) and during the animation, the content is tied to the bottom, so I the first line of the contend is displayed last.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a callback on the cell and update it's constraints

```
func updateTableViewUIfor(indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    theCell.updateToExpanded() //get the cell and update it's constraints
    self.tableView.setNeedsDisplay()
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

and you use the

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
//... return required height
}
```

Comment: tableView.setNeedsDisplay didn't help. Only tableView.reloadData() after the animation is working.

Answer (score 0):

I've had some issues with iOS 11 and self-sizing/resizable cells. I don't know eactyl what are the weird behavior for you, but in my case I did set the tableView `estimatedRowHeight` to a value greater than my max cell height and it solved it.

Comment: I had different bug, I described it in question comment. But thank you for your input. Might help someone else.